# ember.js submitting and reading input hidden in controller

Tags: javascript, forms, ember.js

I'm new in **ember.js**, and I get stucked soon trying to **submit a form containing a hidden field**.
The goal is to build a simple login form with a hidden field to prevent crsf attacks.

When I submit the form triggering the **doLogin** action of the controller I can read all the input values passed by the form except for the hidden one.

here's my view code using Ember Easy Form:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="login/index">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <section class="span5 offset6" id="login">
            {{#form-for controller}}
                {{view Ember.Select name="pref" 
                    valueBinding="pref"
                    content=prefix
                    optionValuePath="content.id"
                    optionLabelPath="content.name"
                    prompt="choose a prefix"}}
                {{#input auth}}
                    {{input-field auth placeholder="phone number"}}
                {{/input}}
                {{#input token}}
                    {{input-field token as="hidden" value="121353262ae656256ffd236"}}
                {{/input}}
                {{#input pswd}}
                    {{input-field pswd as="password" placeholder="password"}}
                {{/input}}
                <button {{action "doLogin" target="controller" }}>login</button>
            {{/form-for}}
        </section>
    </div>
</script>
```

here are the route, the controller and the underlying object:

```
App.LoginIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return Indoona.Login.create();
    },
    setupController: function(controller, model) {
        controller.set("model", model);
        Ember.$.getJSON('http://my_rest_api.tld/voip/prefixes', function (response){
            controller.set('prefix', response);
        });
    }
});

App.LoginIndexController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    actions: {
        doLogin: function(){
            var loginObj = this.get("model");
            console.log('auth: ' + loginObj.auth);
            console.log('pswd: ' + loginObj.pswd);
            console.log('pref: ' + loginObj.pref);
            console.log('token: ' + loginObj.token);
        }   
    },
    prefix: []
});

App.Login = Ember.Object.extend({
    pref : "",
    auth : "",
    password : "",
    token : ""
});
```

I've tried putting `valueBinding` inside the hidden with no results
I've tried using native ember input helper with no results
I've tried using native Ember view to render hidden field with no results

Someone could give me a hint?

Comment: why are you using the hidden input here? couldn't you just hold the value in your controller instead of writing it to the DOM and read it again? which version of `Ember.js` are you using for your project?

Comment: thank for the answer @herome, I'm using emebr 1.3.0 and I've already decided to store the token in the controller. No need to pass it to the view of course. But I also solved the problem using `{{view Ember.TextField name="token" type="hidden" valueBinding="token"}}`

Comment: I don't think you need the *Binding and I could be wrong but I also think it's deprecated to use it... so `{{view Ember.TextField value=token}}` should also work just fine ;)